# How to plot a saved signal in Matlab Simulink in the rate it was originally sampled in

Tags: plot, simulink

I have a saved data of a signal that was sampled in a specific sampling rate, fs, for a duration of a few minutes.

I would like to plot the signal for the same duration during which it was sampled, and see it updating, as if it was a real time simulation. Is that possible in Matlab Simulink?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a *From Workspace* block in simulink and directly plot it on scope using AutoSolver(automatic step size)?